# Calculate the summation of double continued fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

A few month ago, my brother had given me this question:
\begin{equation}
  \cfrac{1}{2
          + \cfrac{1}{3
          + \cfrac{1}{4 + \cfrac{1}{\cdots+\frac{1}{2005}} } } }+\cfrac{1}{1
          + \cfrac{1}{2
          + \cfrac{1}{3 + \cfrac{1}{\cdots+\frac{1}{2005}} } } }
\end{equation}
He said to me, "this is called continued fraction and the answer equals 1." Since then, I learned from many websites about CF but I failed to prove the summation of those CFs equals 1. I only see this pattern:
\begin{equation}
  \cfrac{1}{2
          + \frac{1}{3}
}=\frac{\color{green}3}{\color{red}7}\text{ and }\cfrac{1}{1
          + \cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{3}}
}=\frac{\color{red}7}{10}=\frac{\color{red}7}{\color{green}3+\color{red}7}\text{, etc.}
\end{equation}
Let's say the first CF equals $\frac{a}{b}$, then the second CF will equal $\frac{b}{a+b}$. Hence
\begin{equation}
\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a+b}=\frac{a^2+ab+b^2}{ab+b^2}=1+\frac{a^2}{ab+b^2}>1
\end{equation}
Is this correct? Did my big brother trick me all this time? Someone here please help me, preferably someone with a doctorate degree in math or a college math professor so I  can be sure that I'm right and can argue with him. I want to win this time because he always shows off his smartness to me. BTW, I'm just an 8th grade student, so please be nice to me. Thank you. :)

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  Your brother is mistaken.

Comment: @MJD why did you delete your answer? I didn't read it yet. T_T

Comment: I answered your question too quickly.  After I read your analysis, I realized I had added nothing new to what you had already said, which is exactly correct.

Comment: When you append a new term to the bottom of a continued fraction, the value of the fraction changes by a small amount, and the amount of the change is smaller if the new term is larger. The value of the fraction changes by the most if you append a 1 to the bottom, by a smaller amount if you append a 2 to the bottom, and by a very small amount if you append a 2005 to the bottom. Viewed in this light, it is not surprising that the value of $$x =  \cfrac1{2
+ \cfrac1{3
+ \cfrac1{4+ \cfrac{1}{\cdots+\frac1{2005}} } } }$$ is close to $\cfrac1{2+\cfrac13}=\frac37$; it is around 0.433127.

Comment: @MJD How did you get $x=\frac{3}{7}$? Could you please elaborate? You may answer it below. I'll appreciate it your answer. ;)

Comment: I didn't say $x=\frac37$; it said it was *close to* $\frac37$, and is actually a bit more. I had the computer calculate the value 0.4333127. Your answer already says that $x\approx \frac37$, so I didn't think I was telling you anything new.

Comment: @MJD Sorry Sir, but how did you get that number? You really surprised me. It looks like magic to me.

Comment: To get the 0.4333127 I wrote a small computer program to perform the four thousand arithmetic operations in the same way that you would perform them if you were doing them by hand. It did not do anything magical; everything was ordinary, except that it did the ordinary calculations very fast.  Later today I will write an answer explaining some of the theory of continued fractions.  But the calculation of 0.4333127 did not require any of that theory.

Comment: @MJD Yippee! Please write down the answer explaining some of the theory of continued fractions. My math teacher never teaches me about CF. Even he doesn't teach me integral yet. I learn math because I don't wanna lose to him.

Comment: I hope you find my answer interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I would like to reiterate that:

1. Your brother's claim is incorrect
2. The proof you gave that your brother is wrong is quite correct
3. It is very similar to what I would have written myself

Just for completeness, here is what I would have said: Let $x$ be the left-hand term in your brother's expression.  Then the right-hand term is equal to $\frac1{1+x}$.  Your brother then claims that $$x + \frac1{1+x} = 1.$$  Simplifying the left-hand side we get  $$\frac{x^2+x+1}{x+1} = 1$$ which can happen only if $$x^2+x+1 = x+1$$ so $x^2 = 0$ and $x=0$.  But clearly $x>0$, so your brother's claim is mistaken. This is exactly what you said, except you had $\frac ab$ in place of $x$.

You might also observe that this argument works even if your brother carries the continued fractions on past $2005$ to infinity.

The rest of this note is about continued fractions a little more generally.

---

Instead of the clumsy notation  $$z=a_0+ \cfrac{1}{a_1
          + \cfrac{1}{a_2
          + \cfrac{1}{a_3+ \cfrac{1}{\cdots+\frac{1}{a_n}} } } }$$ let's agree to write $z=[a_0; a_1, a_2,\ldots a_n]$.
Let's consider what happens when we stop early in expanding $z$ and write $$\begin{align}z_0 &= a_0\\ z_1 & = [a_0; a_1] = a_0 + \frac1{a_1}\\
z_2& = [a_0; a_1, a_2] =  a_0+\cfrac{1}{a_1+\cfrac1{a_2}}\\z_3&=[a_0; a_1,a_2,a_3]\\& \;\vdots\\ z  = z_n & = [a_0; a_1,\ldots, a_n]\end{align}$$

These $z_i$ are called the *convergents* of $z$. When $i$ is even we have the *even convergents* and when $i$ is odd we have the *odd convergents*.

Here is the single most important thing to know about continued fractions:

$$z_0\lt z_2 \lt z_4\lt\ldots < z <  \ldots < z_5 < z_3 < z_1
\tag{$\star$}$$

**The even convergents of $z$ form an increasing sequence that approaches the value $z$ from below, while the odd convergents form a decreasing sequence that approaches $z$ from above.**

Let's take $x = [0; 2, 3, 4, \ldots, 2005]$ as in your brother's example.  Taking just the first two convergents we have $0 < x < [0;2] = \frac12$, and taking the next two we have $$0 + \cfrac1{2+\cfrac13} < x < \cfrac1{2+\cfrac1{3+\cfrac 14}}$$ so $$\frac37 < x < \frac{13}{30}\\0.4286\ldots < x < 0.4333\ldots$$ which narrows down the possible value of $x$ rather dramatically. Even without using the computer to calculate the exact value, we now know it is not much more than $\frac37$.

Similarly, let $y$ be the right-hand term of your brother's expression, $[0;1,2,3\ldots, 2005]$. Then we have $$[0] < y < [0;1] = 1\\
[0;1,2] = \frac23 = 0.6666\ldots < y < [0;1,2,3] = \frac7{10} = 0.7.$$

Already this is enough to prove that your brother's claim is mistaken, because we have $$1 < \frac{23}{21}  = \frac37 + \frac 23  < x + y .$$

The book *Continued Fractions* by A. Ya. Khinchin is short,  and the first part is not too hard; you might take a look at it.  Theorem 4 on page 6 is the important fact $(\star)$ that I mentioned above.

Comment: P.S.: I do not have a doctorate, and I am not a mathematics professor, so I cannot help you there. But one of the best things about mathematics is that the correct argument always wins, whether or not the person making it has an advanced degree. You may be in 8th grade, but your idea about $\frac ab$ is a winner.

Comment: Thank you Sir. About doctor and professor, I think I'm too much. I said like that because when I argue with him he always treats me like I'm a child, he always says: "Are you a professor?" or "How old are you so you can teach me this thing?". He always wins the argument by saying that.

Comment: About your answer, it's really simple and easy for me to understand. Once again thank you so much. I really appreciate it. Two thumbs up for you! (y)(y)

Comment: One thing, I don't think my brother made a mistake about this. I believe he has tricked me all this time. He always does that to me.